# mockMvc jUnit testing with @SortDefault and @PageableDefault

Tags: spring, junit, controller, mockmvc

I am trying to test a pagination method which also sorts the content by created date. The method does work how I expect it, however I an unsure how I can correctly test it. Have found no working solution for my problem even the

I know that the issue is caused by @SortDefault being present as when I remove it the problem is solved, could work around it by creating an sql repository call which will sort it asc or desc.

Furthermore the error I currently receive is *java.lang.AssertionError: Content type not set*

tried adding `.setCustomArgumentResolvers(new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver()).build();` but without any luck also tried other methods of `.andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith("application/json"))` also no luck. Still complains that content type is not set.

Below you can see my controller method

```
   @GetMapping("/stuff")
public ResponseEntity<Page<Stuff>> findAllStuffs(@PageableDefault(value = 20) @SortDefault(sort = "created", direction = Sort.Direction.DESC)Pageable pageable){
    log.info("Start of findAllStuffs method");

    Page<Stuff> thePage=repository.findAll(pageable);
    if(thePage==null )
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    else
        return new ResponseEntity<>(thePage,HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Below you can see my test controller method

```
  @Test
public void findAllStuffs() throws Exception {

    PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0,20);
    Page<Stuff> pages = new PageImpl<>(stuffs);
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller).setCustomArgumentResolvers(new SortHandlerMethodArgumentResolver()).build();
    when(repository.findAll(pageRequest)).thenReturn(pages);
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/api/stuffs")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content").isArray())
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.content", Matchers.hasSize(4)))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());

}
```

Any help or suggestions will be truly appreciated.